# Vertical Equivalent of \hfill

Tags: spacing, tex-core

Is there an equivalent of `\hfill` for vertical spacing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try `\vfill`?

Sometimes you need to put in "invisible" objects to get it to work if there is only one thing on the page:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

% An invisible object that \vfill can push to the top of the page
\hbox{}\vfill

% Your content
blah blah blah

% Another object that \vfill can push to the bottom of the page
\vfill\hbox{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}% the star version for the beginning of a page

Without a star the command is ignored

\vfill% an abbreviation for \vspace{\fill}
bar

\newpage
baz
\end{document}
```